# Android exit AsyncTask issue

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to ask if this that looks like an issue to me is problem.

I have a class of AsyncTask to get data from a json file and a doInBackground method with pre-execute and post-execute methods.

At onCreate method of my MainActivity I call the class of AsyncTask with name.execute(). The problem is that the program stuck into the post execute method, is that a problem? There is a way to return to the OnCreate method or should I continue with my code from post execute method?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new LoadAllProducts().execute();
    txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtV);

}

class LoadAllProducts extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading questions. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * getting All products from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        // getting JSON string from URL
        JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url_all_products, "GET", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("All questions: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // products found
                // Getting Array of Products
                questions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_QUESTIONS);

                // looping through All Products
                for (int i = 0; i < questions.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = questions.getJSONObject(i);

                    // Storing each json item in variable
                    int id = c.getInt(TAG_QID);
                    String questionPron = c.getString(TAG_QUESTION);
                    String answer1 = c.getString(TAG_ANSWER_1);
                    String answer2 = c.getString(TAG_ANSWER_2);
                    String answer3 = c.getString(TAG_ANSWER_3);
                    String answer4 = c.getString(TAG_ANSWER_4);
                    int level = c.getInt(TAG_LEVEL);
                    int correctIs = c.getInt(TAG_CORRECT_IS);
                    // String updatedAt = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED_AT);

                    dokimi = questionPron;
                    // creating new HashMap
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    //ArrayList<eachQuestion> qArray = new ArrayList<eachQuestion>();

                    eachQuestion ea = new eachQuestion();

                    ea.setId(id);
                    ea.setQuestionPron(questionPron);
                    ea.setAnswer1(answer1);
                    ea.setAnswer2(answer2);
                    ea.setAnswer3(answer3);
                    ea.setAnswer4(answer4);
                    ea.setLevel(level);
                    ea.setCorrectIs(correctIs);

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    //map.put(TAG_PID, id);
                    //map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                    qArray.add(ea);




                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();
        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {


            }
        });

    }



}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "program stuck into the post execute method"

Comment: There's no way to return to `OnCreate()`. Seems to me that you need to read more about basic Android programming, and asynchronous calls

Comment: `new LoadAllProducts().execute();` returns immediately and `onCreate` is probably completed before the task even starts executing. The code in `onPostExecute` will be executed after `doInBackground` returns (which can basically happen at any time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The problem is that the program stuck into the post execute method, is that a problem?" I can only guess what that was supposed to mean but I will try to answer your question. The reason why AsyncTask even exists is that its code is run on a separate thread (cpu). The main thread (cpu) is making *another* cpu execute given code.

That is why method call of `execute()` returns almost immediately, most probably even before any line of given code for another cpu executes. You are not able to predict when exactly (if ever) this code will execute. This depends on your OS's scheduler and current runtime session, in computer science we describe such behaviour as *undeterministic*.

Comment: ok, thank you very much for this explanation really!
But what's the best way to continue the project, for example if I want to call another activity, should I write the code into onPostExecute or somewhere else?
Excuse me if I am asking "silly" things but I'm trying to figure it out.

Comment: Yes, `onPostExecute()` is a natural way to continue your program workflow after doing things in background. Keep in mind that this method is executed on main thread again, so you should not perform heavy computations there (launching another activity is totally OK though).

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were very helpful!